# Recently, I need a memory-file swapping algorithm

Tags: linux, swap

My boss asked me to find some algorithms or existed libraries.
coz our application runs on linux, and it need lots of files, maybe over 5G-20G....but we dont need to load the files at one time, but at anytime when the file is needed. btw, we have maybe over 100-1000 files stored in our drive.

However, this application is kinda realtime, at least. Simple and ordinary reading or loading can not meet our needs.

I know in linux and windows, there is mechanism virture memory..in linux we use mmap to realize our swapping demands...

But boss is boss, who said we dont take that into consideration presently..

So, i am here prey for helps..
thanx

Comment: What exactly is the question? You want `mmap` but can't use `mmap`. And what does "kinda realtime" mean? Is it a soft real-time system?

Comment: I meant, such system provided functions like mmap are not allowed..i just need some fast and efficient file-memory swapping algorithm. if there are some opensource, It will be more appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your operating system can handle caching and virtual memory (’n stuff) a lot better than you (or any library) can. Apart from simply keeping all files in memory (I heard RAM was cheap :) there’s not much you can do.